# SocketIO4Net - Error initializing handshake with https://localhost/

Tags: socket.io, socketio4net

I'm trying to use SocketIO4Net to connect with my node.js server via socket.io.

Can't seem to get it to work, when it comes to HTTPS. 
Getting this: Error initializing handshake with https://localhost/

Couldn't find a solution in other similar questions.
If you have other solutions to connect to socket.io sockets from C# feel free to share the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET seems to block my self signed certificate. 
Implementing the RemoteCertificateValidationCallback seems to solve the problem.

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(pass);

private static bool pass(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors error) { return true; }